# node-fetch use get method for get a specific file content

Tags: node.js, discord.js, get, node-fetch

I use node-fetch for make requests to localhost.
I want to use get method for get specific file content.
An example: my node.js server is a file called `app.js`, and in the same folder there is a file called `config.json`, so I want to get (from a discord bot made with discord.js) the content of config.json.

Here my server's code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs')
const port = process.env.port || 1451

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`my path`, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
});

app.post('/jsonFile', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

And here is my discord bot code for connecting to my website:

```
fetch('http://localhost:1451').then(res => console.log(res))
```

P.S I use express for node.js servers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use fs.readfile to read that config.json file content and then send that content as a response.